# Can I get some help with making Live USBs?

Tags: 12.04, installation, 13.04, live-usb

I run 13.04 on this laptop and 12.04 on my netbook. I am trying to dual Boot with 13.04 and another distro, but all my Live USBs won't work. I have tried `sudo dd if[ur.iso] of=/dev/sd(x)`, which isn't booting to the live USB but to my Ubuntu installation.

I have tried Unetbootin which gives me a black screens or "This is not a bootable device". I also have tried to do it on my netbook and re-downloading the .iso file. I have now also tried the live disk creator and I get up to the selecting install but it reads "Cannot Mount" in Ubuntu 13.04. I really want to do this and I am desperate for answers. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: What do you mean "do not work?" We can't even guess if it's an issue with booting or your live-usb creation. PLease add what you did, what happened (exactly), what you expected, what you tried (bios? etc)..

Comment: When I used Unetbootin I get a blank black screen or "This is not a bootable disk". Using the command line It just boots to ubuntu.

Comment: you should add the information to the question, if you please :)

Comment: Have you tried other burning app on Ubuntu 13.04, Brasero Disc Burner? K3b? I had similar problem with Ubuntu 13.04 neither of them work but I manage to burn Ubuntu 13.04 on Ubuntu 12.04. I don't know why, but it works. Maybe you should try on another machine or boot through Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try the [LinuxLive USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/):

> LinuxLive USB Creator is a free and open-source software for Windows. It will help you in your journey of discovery with Linux.
>
> For you, LiLi creates portable, bootable and virtualized USB stick running Linux.

Comment: I have now tried that and the program under wine shows up as a black box.